# $G_\delta$ subset of a $G_\delta$ subset is still a $G_\delta$ subset

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

[image]

It seems there is a directly available theorem for (a). What is that? And it seems I am taking (b) too easy. Can I just say the intersection of two countable intersections is still a countable intersection?

My efforts on (b):

Let $X=\cap U_n$ where $U_n$ is an open set in $S$. Let $Y=\cap V_n$ where $V_n$ is an open set in $X$. By definition of relative topology, each $V_n$ can be written as $V_n=W_n\cap X$ where $W_n$ is an open set in $S$. Thus $Y=\cap(W_n\cap X)=X\cap(\cap W_n)=(\cap U_n)\cap(\cap W_n)$. It is still countable intersection of open sets in $S$. So $Y$ is a $G_\delta$ set in $S$.

Comment: I have no idea why (a) was singled out, since, as you saw, (b) is very easy to prove; your proof of (b) is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since
$$Y = \Big(\bigcap_{k \in \mathbb N} U_k \Big) \cap \Big(\bigcap_{\ell \in \mathbb N} W_\ell \Big) = \bigcap_{(k,\ell) \in \mathbb N^2} (U_k \cap W_\ell)$$
and each $U_k \cap W_\ell$ is open in $S$, then $Y$ is a countable intersection of open sets in $S$.